# Rails do not generate html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

Following instruction in 4.2 https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

After using command "rails generate controller Welcome index" 
missing *app/views/welcome/index.html.erb*

Ruby 2.5.5p157 
Rails 5.2.3

My output:

```
  rails generate controller Welcome index
  create  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
  route  get 'welcome/index'
  invoke  test_unit
  create    test/controllers/welcome_controller_test.rb
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the latest version? And can I know your ruby and rails version exactly?

Comment: ruby 2.5.5p157
Rails 5.2.3

Comment: You have mentioned Rails 4.2.x in your question. Have you switched to Rails 5.2.3 just now, and still facing the issue?

Comment: 4.2 is index point from Rails Getting Started guide...

Comment: can you try `bundle exec rails generate controller Welcome index` or `bin/rails generate controller Welcome index` ?

Comment: If that doesn't work, I wonder if you have skipped installing action_view gem explicitly in your Gemfile.

Comment: Still same @imechemi no html.erb. With bin it is not working at all...

Comment: Have you checked your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to see if you have installed `action_view` gem? I can check if you can share your Gemfile ?

Answer (score -2):

First of all, if you are beginning with Rails I would recommend not to go against the conventions that the framework already puts up for you.

Secondly, if you want the welcome which just has no DB connectivity and just for static UI, you can do something like this:

```
$ rails generate controller Welcome index
```

which will create a pages folder inside app/views/welcome/ of your project with .erb templates for the index.

More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's precisely what they did and it didn't work, supposedly (I too think it should have worked. Misconfigured view generator in app settings or something like that?)

Answer (score -3):

Is that all the output you get?

This is mine:

```sh
rails g controller Welcome index                                                                                                                            [ruby-2.6.2@CRC_alpha_blog] 
Running via Spring preloader in process 8696
      create  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
       route  get 'welcome/index'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/welcome
      create    app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/welcome_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/welcome_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/welcome.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.scss
```

What about `helper` and `assets`?

EDIT:
As @imechemi suggests, what's the output if you run the following command?:

```sh
gem list actionview

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionview (5.2.3)
```

Btw, although Rails guides are very good as reference I'd recommend you to follow Michael Hartl's [Rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) if you are learning Rails from scratch.

Comment: all I'm getting is in my first post. And all I'm doing is following Getting Started guide on official rails website....